# How to get an existing stamp annotation in PDF javascript?

Tags: javascript, pdf, annotations, itext

I have used iTextSharp to add a stamp annotation to the PDF file successfully:

```
                PdfReader reader1 = new PdfReader(new FileStream("f:\\1.pdf", FileMode.Open));
                Stream ff = new FileStream(TestTmpFile, FileMode.Create);

                PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader1, ff);
iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("f:\\1.png");
                float w = img.Width;
                float h = img.Height;
                iTextSharp.text.Rectangle location = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(36, 770 - h, 36 + w, 770);
                PdfAnnotation stamp = PdfAnnotation.CreateStamp(stamper.Writer, location, "stampname", "stampname");
                img.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
                PdfContentByte cbb = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
                PdfAppearance app = cbb.CreateAppearance(w, h);
                app.AddImage(img);
                stamp.Name = "stampname";
                
                stamp.SetAppearance(PdfName.N, app);

                stamp.Flags=PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT;
                stamper.AddAnnotation(stamp, 1);
                stamper.Close();
                reader1.Close();
```

I have set the annotation name as "**stampname**", but I cannot get this stamp annotation in PDF javascript by this.getAnnot(). The javasript code in the PDF is:

```
var anno=this.getAnnot(0,"stampname");
```

Did I call the wrong method? Or is this issue related to iTextsharp?

====
EDIT:
I have uploaded the sample PDF file, it contains the stamp annotation which is the png image. The javascript entry is located at "9124 0 obj".

https://www.hihisoft.com/sample.pdf

Comment: The attachment properly has its annotation name attribute **NM** set to "stampname" - see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKjv8.png - so what does `getAnnot` look for?

Comment: That been said, the cross references and trailer of the PDF are broken: Your PDF has objects with object numbers 9122, 9123, and 9124 but the cross references only refer to objects 0...318 and the trailer says **Size** is 319. This is not an error typical for iText, it looks more like someone copied&pasted the annotation into your PDF with respecting requirements of PDF.

Comment: Thanks mkl, may I know what tool you used? It seems very useful.

Comment: The screen shot in my first comment has been made from iText RUPS. The observations in my second comment i made using a regular text viewer (the Total Commander built-in one).